# How to add destination parameter in hook url_inbound_alter

Tags: 7, uri

Hi I have used  [hook_url_inbound_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7) to alter the URL. When I access user/%/order anonymously it should redirect ti user/login. I have used below code

```
 function module_url_inbound_alter(&$path, $original_path,
 $path_language) {   
  $argument = explode('/', $path);  
  if (!user_is_logged_in() && isset($argument[0]) && $argument[0] == 'user' && isset($argument[2]) && $argument[2] == 'orders') {
      $path = 'user/login';

   } 
}
```

It redirects the user to login page but my question is how to add destination parameter. Above code redirects `localhost/drupal/user/login`
but I want to add destination paramater such as `localhost/drupal/user/login?destination=user/1/order`

When I tried to  add the desination variable in `$path` variable

> $path = '/user/login?destination=user/1/order;

I am getting the url like this

> http://localhost/drupal/user/login%3Fdestination%3Duser/1/order

Instead it should be like this.

> http://dt.drop/user/login?destination=user/1/order

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular problem (redirect an anonymous user to user/login), it can be better to redirect on form submit. So, on hook `form_submit()` you check whether `user_is_logged_in()`, if not `drupal_goto('user/login')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the destination parameter to $_GET as such:

```
$path = 'user/login';
$_GET['destination'] = 'user/1/order';
```

The parameter will be picked by whatever interested parties as if it was a part of the original URL. Since the $path is already parsed it doesn't seem to allow to add the ?parameters.
This is acceptably clean as all the code is one place, no need to alter the form elsewhere.